# GDB disassembly address different when adding breakpoint

Tags: gdb, disassembly

Here is my function with line numbers

```
8 |  void function(char* string) {
9 |       char buffer[16];
10|      strcpy(buffer,string); 
11|  }
```

Here is gdb `disassemble function` output

```
0x000011d4 <+0>:    push   %ebp
0x000011d5 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x000011d7 <+3>:    push   %ebx
0x000011d8 <+4>:    sub    $0x14,%esp
0x000011db <+7>:    call   0x123d <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
0x000011e0 <+12>:   add    $0x2e20,%eax
0x000011e5 <+17>:   sub    $0x8,%esp           <---- I want Break point here
0x000011e8 <+20>:   pushl  0x8(%ebp)
0x000011eb <+23>:   lea    -0x18(%ebp),%edx
0x000011ee <+26>:   push   %edx
0x000011ef <+27>:   mov    %eax,%ebx
0x000011f1 <+29>:   call   0x1030 <strcpy@plt>
0x000011f6 <+34>:   add    $0x10,%esp
0x000011f9 <+37>:   nop
0x000011fa <+38>:   mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ebx
0x000011fd <+41>:   leave  
0x000011fe <+42>:   ret
```

If I set break point at `0x000011e5`  using the following command,

```
(gdb) b *0x000011e5
```

and run the program, gdb ignores all breakpoints and exits.

But, if I specify,
`b 9`, it works.
Here is the output

```
(gdb) b 10
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4011e5: file hello.c, line 10.
```

Why are the address different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are the address different

Because you have a position-independent executable, which is linked at address 0, but relocated to a different address at runtime.

Comment: Can I get runtime address of a function in `gdb` ?

Comment: @AdityaSinghRathore Sure: `print &function` _after_ you have started running the binary.